# Convex symmetric octagon diagonals projections property

Tags: geometry

We are given an arbitrary convex octagon ABDFHGEC which is symmetric with respect to axis MN and has no vertices on that axis. One side of octagon orthogonal to axis MN is AB and another side orthogonal to MN is GH. Diagonals CD and EF are orthogonal to axis MN. B and H are on the same side of symmetry axis MN, and they are connected by diagonals BE and HC to vertices E and C on other side of octagon so that diagonals BE and HC cross at point X. O is orthogonal projection of X on MN. Through point O we draw two symmetric with respect to MN lines IJ and LK crossing octagon at points I, J, L, K, the angle between lines IJ and LK is such that interval ST, where S and T are points of intersection of IJ, LK and line CD, is equal to CQ, where point Q is intersection of line CD with diagonal BE. It is easy to see that points I, J, L, K belong to sides CA, HF, EG, BD of octagon. I wish to prove that h, orthogonal projection of both IJ and LK on axis MN, is larger than minimal of h1 and h2, orthogonal projections of diagonals BE and HC on axis MN.

[image]